# What's the difference between DMA Controller and I/O processor

Tags: io, hardware, dma

Given the starting memory address & word count DMA controller transfers data while the CPU works on some other process.
The Input Output processor too handles I/O processes given the starting address & word count..
(correct me if I'm in error)

So what's the difference in functionality between IOP & DMA controller?

Comment: And also are DMA controllers a part of the IOP?

Comment: dma controllers dont always do the transfer while the cpu does other things, sometimes the cpu is held while the dma happens.  It depends on the system.  YOu have not specified the system.  I assume the answer to your question is x86 based and has to do with the difference between I/O and memory interfaces.

Comment: They're synonyms. An IOP is the same thing as a DMA controller. As wikipedia can tell you.

Comment: It's also obsolete mostly, so there's that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  case of memory specific I/O operations (Simple example instructions  like lw $r1,$r2,16 in case of MIPS processor), CPU needs to  get the data from memory,to facilitate I/O operations. And so CPU has to pause any other operation and monitor the memory READ/WRITE  operation till it is not completed. In other words **CPU is totally  occupied as long as read/write operation is in progress without DMA** .If the  processor was free during this time,then processor could have executed  some other instructions .

## Direct Memory Access(DMA):

DMA  provides this capability to carry out memory specific operations with  minimal CPU intervention. When any I/O device needs a memory  access. It sends a DMA request(in form of interrupt) to CPU. **CPU initiates the the transfer by providing appropriate grant signals to the data bus**. And passes the control to the DMA controller  which controls the rest of the data transfer and transfers the data  directly to I/O device. During this time, CPU continues with  other instructions. Once the Read/Write operation in completed (or any  exception is occurred )the DMA controller initiates an interrupt and  notifies the processor about the status of read/write operation.

In  this way **the read/write operation is also carried out and CPU also executes some other instruction during that time. However, initialization of DMA still requires CPU intervention.** And so the  overall performance is maximized.

## I/O processor

You can think I/O processor along the lines of DMA approach.
**The I/O processor, generally used in large computer systems, is a coprocessor which is capable of executing the instructions in addition to transfer of data.** By the way, the coprocessor instruction system is different from the central processing unit.

**CPU can execute the I/O specific program by initializing the basic operations like enabling the data path and setting up the I/O devices participating in operation.** And then it transfers the task to I/O  processor,which then carry out rest of the tasks and upon completion  notifies the processor. The processor meanwhile executes other important  instructions.

The I/O processor is essentially a small DMA dedicated processor that can execute limited input and output instructions and can be shared by multiple peripherals.

**The I/O processor solves two problems:**

- The job of input and output is assumed by the CPU.
  Although DMA does not require CPU for data exchange between peripherals and memory, it only reduces the burden of CPU. Because in DMA, the initialization of input and output is still done by CPU.
- The problem of sharing DMA interface of high speed equipment in large computer system. A large computer system peripherals so much that it had to share the DMA interface Limited (small computer systems such as PC in each device is assigned a DMA high speed interface).

Answer (score 1):

DMA is a hardware module able to transfer data between a peripheral and memory (UART, SPI, DAC, ADCs) or two differents memory addresses without consuming CPU processing time. Generally, configuirng DMA modules involves setting up a memory destination address  and a source address, also users are able to configure options such as: buffer data size, automatic address increment and circular buffer. Moreover, these kind of module emits a IRQ signal at the end of the data transfer.

There is a DMA configuration example below for the microcontroller STM32F373. The example shows a DMA configuration between sigma-delta ADC and a memory buffer.

```
DMA_InitTypeDef  DMA_InitStructure;
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA2, ENABLE);
DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Channel3);

/* DISABLE the DMA SDADC1 channel */
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Channel3, DISABLE);
/* DMA channel SDADC1 Configuration */
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = bufferSize;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&SDADC1->JDATAR;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr = (uint32_t)memoryAddress;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize =  DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M = DMA_M2M_Disable;

DMA_Init(DMA2_Channel3, &DMA_InitStructure);

/* Avoid interrupt on DMA ENABLE */
DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA2_FLAG_TC3);

// Enable DMA2 Channel Transfer Complete interrupt
DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Channel3, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);

/* Enable the DMA channel */
DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Channel3, ENABLE);
```

Regarding to I/O processor, I didn't understand it all what did you you mean. But I can say that GPIO hardware modules are able to map general digital input/output to a memory address, i.e: The I/O I/o has a memory address, but read and write operations in fact are done in a peripheral register.

Comment: while true, this does not answer the question of "what's the difference between an ios and a dma controller" at all.

Comment: So I did some research in the Internet and read that it is just a matter of nomenclature. DMA and I/O processor refers to the same thing.

Comment: That's what my comment above says :)

Comment: So I did some research in the Internet and read that it is just a matter of nomenclature. DMA and I/O processor refers to the same thing. What I could find is that DMA controller complexity varies from architecture to architecture. For example: In a Microcontroller architecture, DMA will be able only to copy data from peripheral to memory, whitout executing any logic, while in specific data center oriented architectures DMAs can have a small and specific instruction set able to seek for Keys.